# 2 faux columns, liquid in the middle & a sticky footer without a bg on the html/body?

Tags: html, css, footer, multiple-columns

I am working on a 2 faux side-columns, liquid in the middle and a footer layout and managed and managed to get it working with sacrifice:

http://jsfiddle.net/8F2my/

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <div id="header">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <span>Copyright &copy; 2011-2014 FDNA Inc., All rights reserved.</span>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

html, body {height: 100%;}

html {
    /* I don't like doing this */
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VEIy.png') repeat-y left;
}

body {
    /* I don't like doing this */
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VEIy.png') repeat-y right;
    font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", "FreeSans", sans-serif;
    min-width: 1000px;
}

.wrapper {min-height: 100%; }

.main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}  /* must be same height as the footer */

/* Head area */

#header {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3498db;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #3498db;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 40px;
    clear:both;
}

.footer span {
    margin: 10px 0 0 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

As you can see the faux column background is assigned to the body and the html. Is there any way I could achieve the same thing in a clean way without assigning a background to the html and body?

This is how it looks if you don't want to click the link:

[image]

The white part is liquidy and the gray is of a fixed size.

I am using this faux:

[image]

This is not a javascript/jQuery question.

Comment: Try using [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sure!

One way is to make use of a CSS table for your 'columns' (I assume you mean sidebars) and absolute positioning to get the layout correct.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F2my/2/)

HTML

```
<header></header>
<div class='content'>
<div class='columns'>
    <div class='column'></div>
    <div class='column'></div>
    <div class='column'></div>
</div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header, footer {
    background-color: #3498db;
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
footer {
    bottom:0;
}
.content{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    bottom:40px;    
}
.columns {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    height:100%;
}
.column {
    display:table-cell;
}
.column:first-child, .column:last-child {
    background:#c0c0c0;
    width:305px;
}
```

Comment: It looks syntactically great but doesn't work when there is a lot of content inside. for instance when I added a bunch of line breaks, they went bellow the footer.

Comment: I thought of this myself. It's a change where the footer doesn't get pushed down but it is a far more syntactically elegant solution than the one I had with negative margins and floats. :)